# expectation value of a random variable over a transformation of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider an array of size $m$ where each element is sampled from a uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, e.g., $\mathbf{p}=(0.24,0.03,0.85)$ for $m=3$. Now we sample from this array $\mathbf{p}$ in the fashion of Bernoulli's, e.g., $(0,0,1)$, that is, each element takes the value 1 with probability given from the respective element of $\mathbf{p}$ and the value 0 otherwise. We repeat $n$-times sampling the 0-1 valued arrays
\begin{gather*}
(0,0,1)\\
(1,0,1)\\
(0,1,1)\\
(0,0,1)\\
\vdots
\end{gather*}
Then we construct an array $\mathbf{q}$ counting how many times each 0-1 valued array occurs. For eaxmple, $(0,0,1)$ may occur 10-times and (1,0,1) occurs $25$-times for $n=100$. Then we sort the array $\mathbf{q}$ in the decreasing fashion and sum the first $k$ values, denoting as r. What is the expectation value of $r/n$?

Here is a [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W2x3k3ENhByEiRI5jcNkxX0UKiH1ecgD?usp=sharing) notebook experimenting on the setting $m=10,n=10^4,k=10$ which gives $r/n=0.304(4)$.

Comment: Here are my initial thoughts regarding this problem.

Let $X$ represents the outcome of *one* entry in *one* $m-$dimensional array.

Then $X|P=p\sim Bernoulli(p)$ where $P\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$. Using the total law of probability, $$P(X=1)=\int_{0}^1P(X=1|P=p)f_P(p)dp=\int_{0}^1pdp=\frac{1}{2}$$ This shows $X\sim Bernoulli(1/2)$. Now suppose we take $X_1,\dots ,X_m$ to be identical copies of $X$. By independence we see $$P\Big((X_1,\dots ,X_m)=(x_1,\dots ,x_m)\Big)=\frac{1}{2^m}$$ for any $(x_1,...,x_m)\in \{0,1\}^m$. (I'm still thinking about it)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ represents the outcome of *one* entry in *one* $m-$dimensional array.

Then $X|P=p\sim Bernoulli(p)$ where $P\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$. Using the total law of probability, $$P(X=1)=\int_{0}^1P(X=1|P=p)f_P(p)dp=\int_{0}^1pdp=\frac{1}{2}$$ This shows $X\sim Bernoulli(1/2)$. Now suppose we take $X_1,\dots ,X_m$ to be identical copies of $X$. By independence we see $$P\Big((X_1,\dots ,X_m)=(x_1,\dots ,x_m)\Big)=\frac{1}{2^m}$$ for any $(x_1,...,x_m)\in \{0,1\}^m$. Next, for fixed $(x_1, \dots ,x_m)\in\{0,1\}^m$, take $Y_{(x_1, \dots ,x_m)}$ to be a random variable counting the number of times $(x_1, \dots ,x_m)$ appears in your sample of $n$ $m-$ dimensional arrays. Then $Y_{(x_1, \dots ,x_m)}\sim Binomial\Big(n,\frac{1}{2^m}\Big)$ and so $$\mathbb{E}\Big(Y_{(x_1, \dots, x_m)}\Big)=\frac{n}{2^m}$$ Now if $E\subseteq \{0,1\}^m$ has size $k\in[2^m]$ and $R=\sum_{(x_1, \dots ,x_m)\in E}Y_{(x_1, \dots, x_m)}$ then we have $$\mathbb{E}\bigg(\frac{R}{n}\bigg)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{(x_1, \dots , x_m)\in E}\mathbb{E}\Big(Y_{(x_1, \dots, x_m)}\Big)=\frac{k}{2^m}$$

Any suggestions, recommendations, advice, etc. are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I feel like $R$ doesn't take into account that we sort the outcome $Y$.

Comment: I tried to capture the sorting by keeping the set $E$ as arbitrary as possible.